# Merge [tags], [tagging] and [retagging]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Those three **meta** tags are basically the same thing, and for the sake of cleanness we should merge them:

- [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging)
- [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)
- [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging)

I would propose the tag synonym, but it won't let me (because apparently I don't have the necessary rep in that tag.)

Comment: I also agree with merging them, I'll leave it a day or so and see what consensus we arrive on for the final tag

Comment: The community seems torn, or rather doesn't care which tag it's going to be. ;) I'd say just pick one of the two and change it. @iandotkelly

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with the general idea of merging them all together, I would rather settle for [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) as the umbrella term.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses `tags` and redirects `tag` and `tagging`. So, I guess that sounds like a best practice. It's the same on Arqade. They don't have a `retagging` tag at all but they do have `retag-request`, which we don't (but apparently a request for that tag was declined).

Comment: @iandotkelly community decision looks clear.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

Consolidate them all under [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging), which I think best sums up what the tagged questions are about.